# how to update a subitem of a listview which has got a image in .net winforms

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a listview in .net winforms. I add images to both items as well as subitems in listview.
while editing the subitem how to drwa the image of the subitem of listview?

Comment: How did you add images to SubItems and how are you *editing the subitem*? Post your code.

Comment: through drawsubitem event and editing the listviewitems subitem property

Comment: As mentioned, you're supposed to post the code you need help with.